# How to open 'google-services.json' folder?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to download and open 'google-services.json' folder.
I faced the problem that whenever I downloaded this file, I could't open it.

According to popup message,

' The computer doesn't have a connecting application to implement the file. Install the application or make a connection in basic app setting page if you already install it'

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that requires you to open it?  All the Firebase instructions say that you just need to copy it into your project.  It just contains JSON.

Comment: Hello. I was adding my application to firebase. And that error happend

Comment: It was folder. I couldn't open the folder containg json files.

Comment: Can't you just simply open the file using any text editor?

Comment: I solved the problem using text editor ! Thanks